# Timer is not working when you call using class name in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

My timer is not working.
Here is the code.

```js
var minutesLabel = document.getElementsByClassName('lol')[0].innerText;
    var secondsLabel = document.getElementsByClassName('lol1')[0].innerText;
    setInterval(setTime, 1000);
    
    function setTime() {
      ++totalSeconds;
      secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
      minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
    }
    
    function pad(val) {
      var valString = val + "";
      if (valString.length < 2) {
        return "0" + valString;
      } else {
        return valString;
      }
    }
```

```html
<label class="lol" id="minutes">00</label>:<label class="lol1" id="seconds">00</label>
```

I have been trying to call it using the class name but i don't get it why it's not working

Comment: "class name" ??

Comment: Both `minutesLabel` and `secondsLabel` are strings, not elements.  `.innerHTML` isn't going to work on them

Comment: The error in the console is also telling you another problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this.

You have many mistakes in your code

1. You haven't definefed `totalSeconds`
2. you have defined `minutesLabel` like this `var minutesLabel = document.getElementsByClassName('lol1')[0].innerText;` and inside `setTime` function you used as `minutesLabel.innerHTML`. which is wrong.
3. You have swapped mins and secs calculation

```js
var min = document.getElementsByClassName('lol')[0];
var sec = document.getElementsByClassName('lol1')[0];
setInterval(setTime, 1000);
var totalSeconds = 0;
function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  sec.innerText = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
  min.innerText = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
}

function pad(val) {
  var valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString;
  } else {
    return valString;
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="lol" id="minutes">00</label>:<label class="lol1" id="seconds">00</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Few changes:

- Initialize totalSeconds before an increment
- I suggest you use **document.getElementById**
- Using **.innerText** returns element value, but you need DOM element and its methods.

  ```
  var minutesLabel = document.getElementById('minutes');
  var secondsLabel = document.getElementById('seconds');
  var totalSeconds = 0;

  setInterval(setTime, 1000);

  function setTime() {
    ++totalSeconds;
    secondsLabel.innerText = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
    minutesLabel.innerText = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
  }

  function pad(val) {
    var valString = val + "";

    if (valString.length < 2) {
      return "0" + valString;
    } else {
      return valString;
    }
  }
  ```